# How do I get the selected item from a Gridview with ImageAdapter? (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, selecteditem

I had used a ListView to show some data (String) retrieved from the database...quite simple, but one of my cooworkers decided to put an image in front of the text in the screen. We were not able to do it with Listview, but we found some example with GridView that looked exactly as we need then we spent some time using GridView and did put the image in the front of the text.

Now, unfortunately we don't know how to get the selected item (based on the Text that comes from the item selected)

I'm using OnItemClickListener, and within onItemClick the method gridView.getItemSelectedAtPosition(), but everything i get is "null".

I don't now if ImageAdapter has something to do with it, cuz if I change it to an ArrayAdapter I can get the right item properly but there is no image in the row in this way.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id{     String selectedItem = (String) (gridView.getItemAtPosicion(position)); //always null     } });
```

what can I do?

EDITED   - ListView source

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] mobileValues;
private final String[] mobileValuesD;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues, String[] mobileValuesD) {
this.context = context;
this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
this.mobileValuesD = mobileValuesD;
}

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService           (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View gridView;

  if (convertView == null) {

  gridView = new View(context);

   // get layout from mobile.xml
    gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pesquisa_2, null);

  // set value into textview
    TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
     textView.setText(mobileValues[position]+"\n"+mobileValuesD[position]);

 // set image based on selected text
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

  String mobile = mobileValues[position];

 //SELECT DAS IMAGENS

  if (mobile.equals("pdt1")) {
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
  } else if (mobile.equals("prd2")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.feijao);
   } else {
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.acucar);
    }


   } else {
    gridView = (View) convertView;
   }

    return gridView;
 }

   public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
 }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
 }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
 }

 }
```

Comment: And how your image adapter's code looks like?

Comment: @TomaszGawel the only thing we did was to set the Adapter gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, name_array, description_array));

Comment: but ImageAdapter is not a standard class so provvide the code of ImageAdapter class, as i suspect it's getItem method simply returns null for your case.

Comment: @TomaszGawel sorry, I really thought it was a standard class as it was not me who changed the Listview to Gridview I don't know everything that were made...by the way you are right, the method is returning null, do you have any idea how can I write it to get me the text on the row selected??? thx

Comment: how could I if you didn't provide the source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gridView.getItemAtPosition(position)` calls the adapter's `getItem(int position)` under the scene - so implement `getItem` in your `ImageAdapter` class to return sth that will allow you to identify what is selected (maybe `mobileValues[position]` is enough or  just what you write into textview: `mobileValues[position] + "\n" + mobileValuesD[position]`).

On the other hand side in `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)` you have allready have the position of selected item maybe it is enough information? what you are about to do in that listener?

I have put some changes to your adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final String[] mobileValues;
    private final String[] mobileValuesD;

    public ImageAdapter(String[] mobileValues, String[] mobileValuesD) {
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
        this.mobileValuesD = mobileValuesD;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = ViewGroup.inflate(
                    parent.getContext(), R.layout.pesquisa_2, null);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                .setText(getItem(position));

        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image))
                .setImageResource(getImageResForPosition(position));

        return view;
    }

    private int getImageResForPosition(int position) {
        String mobile = mobileValues[position];
        if (mobile.equals("pdt1")) {
            return R.drawable.img1;
        } else if (mobile.equals("prd2")) {
            return R.drawable.feijao;
        } else {
            return R.drawable.acucar;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mobileValues[position] + "\n" + mobileValuesD[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tomasz Gawel! now everything is running perfectly!

Comment: how to get the Class data via recylerview getItemAtPosition(position) when item clicked.