# Android get specific value on array on other class

Tags: java, android

I have an array on my Activity which consist R.drawables images declared inside a 
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter.
So it consists of

```
private   Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.medal_my_first_perxtamp_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_you_complete_me_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_the_gift_of_sharing_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_gimme_5_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_a_cup_of_coffee_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_seven_up_gray,
            R.drawable.medal__gray,
            R.drawable.medal_midnight_madness_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_loyalista_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_15_30_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_kmh_gray,
            R.drawable.medal_champion_gray
            };
```

Now on my class that extends my activity how can I call that array and get a specific value? Sorry for a simple question but I am new to this Android Development

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add this one, a declaration to get the length of that array which is also stored inside ImageAdapter class

```
  public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }
```

And added this code for getter

```
public  Integer[] getImageIDs()
    {
        return this.imageIDs;
    }
```

*Sir*
This is the code i am trying to create on my other class that Extends a activity

```
 GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {   
             //Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
            // clicked picture here
            Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Integer[] imageIDs = ImageAdapter.this.getImageIDs();
            //for (Integer imageId : ImageAdapter.getImageIDs()){
                //  System.out.println(imageId );
                //}
        }
    });
```

See that I can get the position but I dont want to use those tutorial using if else 
[Tutorial Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769989/how-do-i-get-the-selected-item-from-a-gridview-with-imageadapter-android) because I think it will be a long if else. What I am thinking is that since I have a array why cant I use that to get what I am looking for

Comment: Do you want to display that array of images on your listview or spinner?

Comment: No sir I just want to get that list of array because I need specific value stored on that array

Comment: @nick I already done that sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have two options, either the Object Oriented way, and create a getter with a `public`/`protected`/`default` access modifier or else, just declare the array `public`/`protected`/`default` instead of private.

This should allow you to access the array in your extending class. If you just want to be able to access the array in the class which extends your class, just declare the array or getter method as `protected`.

So, you could do something like so:

```
public ActivityClass
{
    private Integer[] imageIDs = ...;

    protected Integer[] getImageIDs()
    {
        return this.imageIDs;
    } 
}
```

And then in your extending class:

```
public SomeOtherClass extends ActivityClass
{
    ...    
    Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
    ...
}
```

After seeing this:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {   
             //Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
            // clicked picture here
            Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Integer[] imageIDs = ImageAdapter.this.getImageIDs();
            //for (Integer imageId : ImageAdapter.getImageIDs()){
                //  System.out.println(imageId );
                //}
        }
    });
```

The problem is that this piece of code:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
            View v, int position, long id) 
            {   
                 //Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
                // clicked picture here
                Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Integer[] imageIDs = ImageAdapter.this.getImageIDs();
                //for (Integer imageId : ImageAdapter.getImageIDs()){
                    //  System.out.println(imageId );
                    //}
            }
        });
```

Is a class within itself (known as an [Inner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)). As far as the compiler is concerned, you are no longer within the class which extends from your activity. That would explain why the compiler complained like so: `The method getImageIDs() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}`.

To go around this, all you need to do would be something like so:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    final Integer[] imageIDs = this.getImageIDs();

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {   
            for (Integer imageId : imageIDs){
                System.out.println(imageId );
            }
        }
    });
```

The code above *should* work. It is important that you get your ID's from outside the event handler, and that you declare the array as final so that it can be passed on to the inner class which is taking care of the event handling.

Comment: adding your code sir gives me an error
getImageIDs cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Actually sir what I am trying to create is when the user clicked on the image which is inside a gridview I can get the selected item. Please se my code above

Comment: @DELLicioso: Yes, sorry my bad, I forgot to add the brackets at the end of the method call. It should now work.

Comment: Now I am getting this error sir
"The method getImageIDs() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}"

Comment: @DELLicioso: I have never done android programming but that is odd... if the `onItemClick` method is present in a class which extends another class which contains a protected getter that error should not be in place.

Comment: I dont know it either sir I tried cleaning my project again but that error still occur

Comment: I think the problem is on the extension:extends BaseAdapter what do you think

Comment: @DELLicioso: Your example shed some light on the problem, you *should* be able to get rid of that error now.

Answer (score 0):

Use public getter method for `imageIDs` :

```
for (Integer imageId : imageAdapter.getImageIDs()){
  System.out.println(imageId );
}
```

Accesing id at perticular index :

```
imageAdapter.getImageIDs()[i];  // i is index of array
```

Comment: Using that code I am getting an error saying "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getImageIDs() from the type MedalsActivity.ImageAdapter"

Comment: you can not call `getImageIDs()` from static method

Comment: Actually it is suggesting that I must put my getter to static but I think it will cause a lot of errror

Answer (score 0):

In your activity make imageIDs protected:

```
protected Integer[] imageIDs = {
...
};
```

Than you can access it from class which extends your activity.