# How to get item from selected row in custom GridView in android?

Tags: android, gridview, onclick, onitemclick

I was looking at this question for a solution to my question( [How do I get the selected item from a Gridview with ImageAdapter? (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769989/how-do-i-get-the-selected-item-from-a-gridview-with-imageadapter-android) ), but I can't find any.

I have a custom GridView with an ImageView and TextView in it and code is-

```
public class ListArray extends BaseAdapter {

Context con;
List<String> obj;
private final int[] Imageid;

public ListArray(Context con, List<String> obj, int[] imageId) {
    this.con = con;
    this.obj = obj;
    this.Imageid = imageId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return obj.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) con
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.liststyle, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewls1);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.imageViewls1);
    tv.setText(obj.get(position));
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[0]);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

This is my Gridview -

[image]

Now I want to read the value in the TextView when clicked on a particular row, for example, I want to get Group1 when clicked on 1st row. So I coded the following -

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "" + arg0.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();                
        }
    });
```

Besides getSelectedItem() I tried some other functions along with arg0, but nothing gave me the desired result.

Can someone tell me how to read the particular value from Gridview ?

Comment: you can get item from arraylist also on list item click.

Comment: @PG_Android How ? Please describe it as an answer.

Comment: What you want to get? Means the name of item like "Group1"?

Comment: @PG_Android I got null, row count(0 and 1), something else like android:layout@..... But I didn't got Group1 or Poly1 when clicked on particular rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        TextView tv =(TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textViewInYourList);//your textview id
        Toast.makeText(myContext,
                "" + tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();                
    }
});
```